# Repack after importing from svn

Tags: git, svn, git-gc

I have imported with [svn2git](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git) a SVN Repo.
Now I left with the choice how to repack/garbage collect the repo to reduce the size, but I dont want to sacrifice the performance of later git operations. How do I do that?

The homepage of the tool suggests:

```
git repack -a -d -f
```

or should I use a really long depth and window:

```
git repack -a -d -f --depth=250 --window=250
```

Does performance of later git operations suffer from these **gc** decisision?

Answer (score 1):

See [this detailed experiment](https://vcscompare.blogspot.com/2008/06/git-repack-parameters.html) for explanation of the effects of these parameters.

Default values for `git gc --aggressive` [are now](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gcaggressiveDepth) 50 and 250 so you can just run `git gc --aggressive` and rely on it having proper defaults.

Comment: But how does that influence my later git performance, e.g `git status`. Is it bad to have only one pack?

Comment: `git status` compares files in the work dir with *index*, not with pack(s). I don't have problems with one pack but I have plenty of memory. For memory-constrained systems (like Arduino, Raspberry Pi, etc) it's perhaps better to have a few smaller packs.